# Mac Mini NAT redirection

Tags: macos, networking, nat

My situation is as follow: an application I am working on works using multiple database servers (MySQL) connections, I work locally and these database servers do not allow connections from anywhere, so I have set up a local test server. How do I redirect all the outgoing traffic to these servers (port 3306) to this local server?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know - even though I never used it yet - you can use the ipfw tool on OSX for similar tasks as you would use iptables for (filtering, address translation etc.). Here you find some more hints: [OSX pfctl manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/pfctl.8.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/8/pfctl)

Comment: I already use a iptables solution on my linux machines: `iptables -t nat -A  OUTPUT -p tcp -d SOURCE_IP --dport 3306 -j DNAT --to-destination DEST_IP:3306`. I'll try this pfctl

Comment: This is what I created: `rdr on en1 proto tcp from any to OLD_IP port 3306 -> NEW_IP port 3306` based on the texts I've read, however, it still does not redirect